# Ruby Rails submit two forms in one click

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these forms:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.number_field :money, :value => @user.money %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and

```
<%= form_for @product, :url => product_path, :html => { :multipart => true }  do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :count, 'How Many product?' %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :count, :value => "1" %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.submit('submit') %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

is there any way to submit this two at once when clicking submit button ? Thanks!

Comment: If the user and product are related, you could use a single form and nested resources. Otherwise, you could use javascript to trigger the submission of the other form.

Comment: This might be a case of "you're doing it wrong".  What reason do you have to post them to two separate actions?  Can you not just handle it all in one single controller?

Comment: You can do this with javascript, sort of. You can't make two requests "at the same time" but you can fire two requests at the same moment (they will resolve one after the other). You _could_ do them both at once if you had an intermediate controller that somehow represented the aggregate of the two models.

Comment: You should be using accepts nested attributes instead of having two forms.

Comment: @Kyle, accepts_nested_attributes are not good advice, they always get you into trouble

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A service object might be a good way to approach this.

```
class Order
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :money, :count

  def initialize(user=nil, product=nil)
    @user = user
    @product = product
    @money = user.money
    @count = 1
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def save
    // this code needs to save to db
  end
end
```